# Consistency of the nonrigidity of $P(\omega_1)/NS$

Tags: set-theory

Is it consistent with ZFC that there exists an automorphism of $P(\omega_1)/\mathrm{NS}_{\omega_1}$ which is not the identity?

Comment: Just off the bat, add $\omega_1$ Cohen reals to $L$?

Comment: @Asaf, is there a natural automorphism to consider in that model?

Comment: I have no idea. It was right off the bat. Because Cohen reals themselves are quite malleable, and the forcing will have plenty of automorphisms. Maybe some of them "seep through".

Comment: (I mean, my guess is as good as any. But if you walked into my office, and asked me this, I'd ask two questions "Is it true/false in $L$, and is it true/false after adding sufficiently many Cohen reals to $L$?", and after we (both of us, if you haven't got the answers prepared in advance) have answers to these, we might be starting on a path to a more concrete answer.)

Comment: I agree that $L$-like models are probably the right place to look, if anywhere (since "$\mathrm{NS}_{\omega_1}$ is saturated and MA$_{\aleph_1}$ holds'' implies $P(\omega_1)/\mathrm{NS}_{\omega_1}$ is rigid, and that stuff is far from $L$).  But I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Diamond and squares. Perhaps adding a generic automorphism using an $\omega_2$-closed forcing, if this can be done.

Comment: Glad to see this conversation spreading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is consistent relative to large cardinals that $P(\omega_1)/NS \cong \mathcal B(\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\omega_1))$ and many other homogeneous algebras.

It almost looks like the answer is yes in $L$, but I'm not sure.  In $L$ there are no precipitous ideals, and GCH holds.  A [theorem of Balcar and Franek](http://ams.rice.edu/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=balcar%20AND%20franek&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=884452) implies that therefore $\mathcal P(\omega_1)/NS$ is forcing-equivalent to $\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\omega_2)$.  Moreover, by general facts about collapsing, there is a dense embedding of $\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\omega_2)$ into $\mathcal P(\omega_1)/NS$.  $\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\omega_2)$ carries many nontrivial isomorphisms, but as Yair pointed out, we may not necessarily be able to lift this to an algebra strictly smaller than the completion.

Comment: It is possible for two posets to be forcing equivalent while one of them is rigid and the other is weakly homogeneous. However, assuming saturation, $P(\omega_1)/NS$ is a complete Boolean algebra, and then the arguments work.

Comment: @YairHayut, what's the example? Doesn't it work here because of the dense embedding?

Comment: Take a tree on $\omega$ such that each node has a different number of successors. This forcing is equivalent to the Cohen forcing, but it is rigid as a partial order (each node is definable).

Comment: Thanks, Monroe.  Do you have a reference for the consistency (relative to large cardinals) of $P(\omega_1)/NS \cong \mathcal{B}(\mathrm{Col}(\omega,\omega_1))$? Or is that easy?

Comment: Not easy at all.  The reference is section 6.2 of Woodin's book.

Comment: I see, thanks!  Since I need a few more characters to make a comment, I'll just say that I'm still interested in whether this holds in $L$, or at least whether it has any large cardinal strength.

Comment: @Yair: Ah yes, that is the much easier example! Originally we thought (of a known example, as it turned out) of the collapse [to $\omega$] of the first $\aleph$-fixed point using a tree where each point has a distinct number of successors. The idea here is similar.

Comment: Also, it's funny. It's not just as Yair pointed out about lifting the automorphisms; it's also the consequence of the answer Paul gave you yesterday on MSE. :-)

Comment: Well not really. An automorphism of a dense subalgebra of a complete Boolean algebra can always be lifted to the whole algebra. Paul pointed out that this is not the case if we replace dense subalgebra by complete subalgebra.